# Activity taking 140mb memory

Tags: java, android, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm trying to create a social media application. But it's taking about 300mb memory. So i had 5 fragments containing posts on my homepage. And overall the memory usage was 250-300mb

Then for testing, I disabled those fragments but still home activity is consuming 140mb without any big operations.

So,

here is my class

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Drawer result = null;
    private Boolean isCoverEdit = false, isProfileEdit = false;
    String username;
    private RelativeLayout splash;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageView searchBtn;
    private AHBottomNavigationViewPager fragContainer;
    private AHBottomNavigation bottomNavigation;
    private ImageView postBtn;
    private View child;
    private ImageView cover;
    private CircleImageView profilePic;
    private TextView star;
    private TextView id;
    private PopupMenu p;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HomePage.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } else {
            getUsername();
            initiateViews();
            setupOnClickListeners();
            setupBottomNavigation();

            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        }


    }
```

Functions

```
    private void initiateViews() {
        splash = findViewById(R.id.splash);
        searchBtn = findViewById(R.id.search);
        fragContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame);
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        bottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        postBtn = findViewById(R.id.post);
        child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        profilePic = child.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        id = child.findViewById(R.id.id);
        cover = child.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        star = child.findViewById(R.id.karma);
    }

 private void getUsername() {
        username = new UserData(this).getUsername();

        if (username==null){
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("username").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    username = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AyePref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("username", username);
                    editor.apply();
                    setupNavigationDrawer();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdata").child(username).child("token").setValue(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }else {
            setupNavigationDrawer();
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdata").child(username).child("token").setValue(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
        }
    }

    private void setupNavigationDrawer() {
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(HomePage.this)
                .withHeader(child)
                .withDisplayBelowStatusBar(false)
                .withTranslucentStatusBar(false)
                .withDrawerLayout(R.layout.material_drawer_fits_not)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Favourites").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_forum),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Settings").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Contact").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_contact_mail),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Commands").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_help),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Log Out").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_security)
                )

                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        if (drawerItem instanceof Nameable) {
                            FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            switch (position) {
                                case 3:
                                    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                                    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"ayesupport@yandex.com"});
                                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                                    break;
                                case 5:

                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    Intent i= new Intent(HomePage.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                    break;
                                case 4:
                                    Intent i2 = new Intent(HomePage.this,CommandsPage.class);
                                    startActivity(i2);
                                    break;

                            }


                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }).build();

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("userdata").child(username).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    Glide.with(HomePage.this).load(dataSnapshot.child("pic").getValue(String.class)).override(100,100).thumbnail(0.5f).into(profilePic);
                    //Glide.with(HomePage.this).load(dataSnapshot.child("cover").getValue(String.class)).into(cover);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                id.setText(username);
                star.setText("4.7");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setupBottomNavigation() {
        AHBottomNavigationItem item1 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Topics", new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_whatshot));
        AHBottomNavigationItem item2 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Rooms", new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_group_work));
        AHBottomNavigationItem item3 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Contacts", new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_people));
        AHBottomNavigationItem item4 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Leaderboard", new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_star));
        AHBottomNavigationItem item5 = new AHBottomNavigationItem("Stats", new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_insert_chart));
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item1);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item2);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item3);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item4);
        bottomNavigation.addItem(item5);
        bottomNavigation.setInactiveColor(R.color.md_grey_800);
        bottomNavigation.setAccentColor(R.color.md_grey_600);
        bottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_HIDE);
        fragContainer.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
        HomePageAdapter adapter = new HomePageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
        //fragContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
        bottomNavigation.setOnTabSelectedListener(new AHBottomNavigation.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTabSelected(int position, boolean wasSelected) {
                //fragContainer.setCurrentItem(position);
                return wasSelected;

            }
        });
    }
```

Full Class : [here](https://pastebin.com/spaw7vy1)
In that class no fragments are added but the memory usage is 120-140

[image: Memory Usage]

I'm sure, I'm repeating the same mistakes in all other activities or fragments. Once I know the problem I can fix it for other parts.
[image: Heap Dump]

Need Help :(

Comment: Take a heap dump and see what classes are using all your memory.  Most likely it will be images.  But we have no way of knowing, you have to do the legwork here.

Comment: I just added the Heap Dump screenshot. It's showing FinalizerReference and com.google.android.gms in top. But how can I know what's the actual object or process which is causing this issue.. Thanks for replying. @GabeSechan

Answer (score 7):

I think it is normal. It is not eating 140MB of RAM actually. On new Android Monitor of AS3 numbers are a bit different than previous AS2. In the [user guide here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html), it is written:

> When compared to memory counts from the previous Android Monitor tool,
>   the new Memory Profiler records your memory differently, so **it might
>   seem like your memory use is now higher**. The Memory Profiler monitors
>   some extra categories that increase the total, but if you only care
>   about the Java heap memory, then the "Java" number should be similar
>   to the value from the previous tool.
>
> **And although the Java number probably doesn't exactly match what you
>   saw in Android Monitor, the new number accounts for all physical
>   memory pages that have been allocated to your app's Java heap since it
>   was forked from Zygote.** So this provides an accurate representation of
>   how much physical memory your app is actually using.
>
> Currently, **the Memory Profiler also shows some false-positive native
>   memory usage in your app that actually belongs to the profiling tools.**
>   Up to 10MB of memory is added for ~100k objects. In a future version
>   of the tools, these numbers will be filtered out of your data.

I used to see 200MB+ on my previous app that has 4 fragments with bottom navigation (and found nothing on Leakcanary).

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help ..

check your

- cover image
- profile picture
- splash screen image

check the `size` of the images they can effect the memory so bad !

in your code you used

```
UCrop.of(absolutePath, Uri.parse(imageURI))
                        .withAspectRatio(16, 9)
                        .withMaxResultSize(1280, 720)
                        .start(HomePage.this);
```

it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView.

thats mean you must be specific or if you need this quality use it but make sure this will cost a lot of memory.

### take a look here

[Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

and there if the images that u use in the project as a splash screen you can use a tools Optimize your images with a perfect balance in quality and file size.

### Tools - check this :

[TinyPNG - Smart PNG and JPEG compression](https://tinypng.com/)

[Optimizilla](http://optimizilla.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check you resources. The drawable folder may contain pictures and also check for musics. Check the splash image size, if there are musics, check the size of it and also for videos.

Comment: It's about RAM memory, not storage. Although it is true that large drawables are increasing the memory usage, your answer is incorrect since you are talking about the storage space used by the app.

Comment: No not only the storage. I am also talking about RAM memory. On the run time, your device should handle your huge App. But many devices wont handle that kind of applications. So it will fail. Let me give u suggestions, change the picture to low resolution images and try it. Hope it will work